# How to hide label based on child value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide an element and a label  based on value:
My html code looks like this

```
<form id="wrapper">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Slider">
        Slider
    </label>
</form>
```

So using jquery i can find an input value that contains `value="Slider"`  but the label still remains, because it it doesn't contain any `id` or `class` and I can't add anything there, so how can I hide it

```
$('#wrapper').find("input[value='Slider']").each(function(){
    $(this).hide()
});
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xsZt/#&togetherjs=0qHznAtG6Q).

Comment: Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 5):

You need to hide the parent `label` element to hide input element and its sibling text:

```
$('#wrapper').find("input[value='Slider']").closest('label').hide();
```

Comment: @Egzona You forgot to attach jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method to checking children of element.

```js
$("label").has("input[value='Slider']").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Slider">
    Slider
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Slider2">
    Slider2
</label>
```

Comment: can I do the same this using javascript without jquery cause I'm having scripts conflicts something like:document.getElementById(' ').style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    $('#wrapper').find("input[value='Slider']").each(function(){
          // $(this).hide();  If you want to hide input too
           $(this).parent().hide();

});
```

Comment: I think no need to give each loop here @poonam .